# Sending file from PC to Arduino

Tags: serial, arduino-yun, serial-data

How can i send a (file) from PC to Arduino Yun at running time ?

There's a way to send some commands via Serial. 
But how would a whole file goes ? Assuming the file can take place at RAM without any problems.

Thanks

Comment: Please be precise about what type of file and content.

Comment: Just use `scp`...

Comment: @leoc7 image file. JPEG extension.

Comment: @Majenko can you guide me to a link or a library ?

Comment: What OS are you using? And what do you want to *do* with the file?

Comment: I am using Windows10 @Majenko .

Comment: And what do you want to do with the file?

Comment: To send it to Internet via Yun. This is a firm part of the Project.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to send a file to the Yun from your PC to then send it on to "The Internet"? Why can't you just send it to "The Internet" direct from your PC?

Comment: It's a new challenge we are seeking to solve, It's an educational purpose.

Comment: Ohkay... seems pretty pointless to me. What kind of connection do you have avaliable to the Yun from your PC? WiFi? Ethernet? USB?

Comment: It's USB. to Serial pin. If it's better to use Ethernet, please guide me to a solution.

Comment: I would suggest using Ethernet or WiFi, then use `scp` (get Putty for Windows for that, or install one of the Linux subsystems) and scp the file over the network. Then you can access that file using Arduino code using the `Bridge.h` library and the `FileSystem` object.

Comment: [See this](https://it.cornell.edu/managed-servers/transfer-files-using-putty), At the end of it they provide an example. But in our case, What would be our 'userid' and 'destination directory' ? We tried a similar approach with no success. 

We've used the IP of the Yun (via Wi-Fi), In case of using Ethernet, What would be different ?

Comment: User ID is probably `root`. Destination directory? Whatever you want. `/tmp` is probably best.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this at nearest time possible. I guess it's going to SD card directory So i don't need a command [at loop] to receive it. That's neat!

Answer (score 1):

You can send a file, byte after byte, using Serial.
On the Arduino side, you parse serial communication and put bytes inside an array. At the end, you reconstruct the file.

Comment: What tool i can use to send that file from PC to Arduino ?

Comment: I think that not exist a tool like this. You should create this PC tool using, for example, Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is what do you want to do with your image : Arduino Yun has a Linux chip & an Arduino chip. 
And I don't think that image treatment must happen in the Arduino side... 
So you can send your image with scp to Linux side, then do what you want with it and perhaps, eventually, send the result for action to the Arduino part.

Comment: I want to send an image, This image is to be attached to an email which would be sent to email address.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the mists of time (late 1990s, if anyone's counting), there existed a file transfer protocol called [XMODEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMODEM) that was used to send a file across a link normally used for a terminal, on small, publicly available systems known as Bulletin Board Systems, or BBSes.
XMODEM divided a file into packets of 129 bytes, sent and acknowledged one packet at a time. It had a simple 8-bit checksum to verify the file contents which was just "ok" over a reasonably reliable line, line and inadequate on a noisy one. But it was one of the first experimenter-built and widely used protocols.

As it was pushed harder and harder (larger file sizes, higher line speeds intolerant of the small, single-packet handshake) and its weaknesses became more problematic,a number of derivatives were developed to address the weaknesses.

[ZMODEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZMODEM) was one of those, which allowed the sender a "sliding window" of packets, so it could keep sending packets (up to the window maximum) without stopping to wait for each acknowledgement, and could use larger packet sizes, among other improvements.

They are relatively easy to implement, XMODEM more-so, and source code or specs can be found by looking around.

If your files aren't horrendously large and the lines are fairly reliable, even XMODEM may be adequate.